# Sort multiple independent vectors of double

Tags: c++, sorting, parallel-processing, gpu

Maybe I was a little bit unclear:

What I want to do i to sort many vectors as fast as possible.
I have for example 200 vectors with 200 double.

Comment: Do you want to sort the elements inside of each vector or do you want to sort all vectors (which Needs an additional category as vectors of numbers don't have an innate order)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted your code, I assume you are looking for a better optimization of code to save memory and time. Try using flags in your loops.

```
for(i=1;x;i++)
{
    sort();
    if(flag)
       break;
}
```

The "break" makes sure that you don't iterate over the unnecessary code after you've sorted your data, the flag tells the compiler to exit the loop statement when the iterations are comlete. Using flags in nested loops is even more important since the space complexity goes over O(n.square) and it calls better efficiency.

This saves a lot of time over huge number of iterations and also memory space. Try optimizing your code wherever possible, makes a lot of difference in the long run.

Comment: I dont have any flag. I will never break. I want to sort a multiple of vectors i parallel fast

Comment: Try going for radix sort,else if you are using a single loop, quick sort will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Radix sort can speedup your sorts.

There is a parallel implementation of the Radix sort algorithm in the Nvidia cuda/openCL SDK.

Comment: Maybe I was a bit unclear, I want to sort many vectors. Not just one big.